# how to install pandoc and pandoc-crossref which correspond

Tags: pandoc

I need `pandoc-crossref` to run in a `pandoc` command. I have installed `pandoc-crossref` with

```
cabal install pandoc-crossref
```

but when I run

```
pandoc --from=combine.lua -F pandoc-crossref --citeproc index.md 0*.md -o res1.pdf
```

I am informed that my pandoc version is older than the pandoc used to produce pandoc-crossref. My naive approach to install the two packages together

```
cabal install pandoc pandoc-crossref
```

was not successful; it installed `pandoc-crossref` but produced no new executable for pandoc.  How to force the installation of a pandoc executable with cabal?

Answer (score 0):

I found some hints indicating that

```
cabal install pandoc-cli
```

installs the pandoc executable, whereas `cabal install pandoc` compiles the library only.

```
cabal install pandoc-cli pandoc-crossref
```

together produce two executables (pandoc and pandoc-crossref) which are working together.